# How to Databind a CheckBox

Tags: c#, sql, database, checkbox, sql-server-2012

How do i data bind a checkbox?

i have a checkbox and a couple of textboxes and a datagrid view. When i click next it goes through the data in the datagrid and updates other values such as a textbox to correspond to the data in the datagrid. This isent working for a check box  though.

```
roomNoTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bsRooms, "RoomNo"));

gymCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bsRooms, "Gym"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the checked property instead:

```
gymCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", bsRooms, "Gym"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try using the checked property instead:
>
> ```
> gymCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", bsRooms, "Gym"));
> ```

This is correct. But the one thing you need to know (which took me half an hour just now), the checkbox needs to validate (with the default setting). So it needs to lose focus for example.

So I found the better solution would be:

```
gymCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", bsRooms, "Gym", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```